# react hooks: Can't create list with map function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, map-function

I have an array of objects that pass as props to child component. in child component I want to map that array to show in a list. but I got this error

> Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

this is my child :

```
const ServiceTabs = (props) => {
  const [parentProps] = props;
  return (
    <ul>
      {
          parentProps.map((content) => (
            <li key={content.id} className="active">
              <BtnButton
                btnStyle={content.btnStyle}
                btnColor={content.btnColor}
                customTitle={content.customTitle}
                IconSRC={content.IconSRC}
              />
            </li>
          ))
}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

and this is my parent:

```
 const ServiceCategory = () => {
      const [serviceState, setserviceState] = useState([
        {
          id: 1,
          customtitle: 'hair', 
          btnStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px',
            flexDirection: 'column',

          },
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          .
          .
          },        
      ]);
.
.
.
 <ServiceTabs list={serviceState} />
```

when i change `const [parentProps] = props;` to `const parentProps = props;` the error changes:

> parentProps.map is not a function
>   i think my problem is destructure of props.but i dont know how to do that. 
>   hope my question was clear.

Comment: Your prop is named `list`, so you'd access that instead: `props.list.map(...`

Comment: oh oh!.thank you men.it worked@Clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be destructuring the list prop like this and then map over that variable:

```
const { list } = props
list.map(content => {...})
```

Here is a working Codesandbox example using (mostly) your code to illustrate what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-pasteur-k8387?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: when i use this way it throw an error >TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: See the codesandbox link above for a working example

Comment: yes, that's working properly.and can you tell me how to fix eslint >'list.map' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types) error? `i mean to show how to add propTypes and defaultProps

Comment: I'd appreciate an upvote if this was helpful, for proptypes just add a propType of `list: arrayOf(Object)` and make sure to `import { arrayOf, Object } from 'prop-types'` set the defaultProps list value to []

Comment: was this the accepted answer? If so could you click on the accepted answer tick to help others who might visit this question?

Answer (score 1):

as @Clarity pointed out in comment I solved the problem by changing

```
const [parentProps] = props;
```

to

```
const parentProps = props;
```

and

```
parentProps.map((content) => (
```

to

```
parentProps.list.map((content) => (
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `const [parentProps] = props;` to `const {list: parentProps} = props;`

Note that the [] in this context is used to destructure arrays, and that is why it shows the error:

> Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

when you are destructuring an object you should pass in the destructor what is the field you want to take from the source object. More info can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: thank you, it worked in this way but eslint give error>' list' is missing in props validation. and i dont want add props validation.

Comment: You are using propTypes?

Answer (score -1):

you should use

```
props.parentProps.map(content => {...})
```

Comment: I don't know because of hook or not but when changing my code  this way that throw error.>Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: above you seem to destructure prop not correctly, it should be:
const {parentProps} = props;
instead of;
const [parentProps} = props;

Comment: this is incorrect, there's no `parentProps` prop passed to child component.

Comment: @Berk Elmas you got it wrong. my props are an array of objects.